# Word Interop Join documents in memory

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I have a List that I would like to join in a single Word.Document.  Below is all that I have so far.

Any ideas?

```
public static Word.Document JoinDocuments(List<Word.Document> DocstoJoin)
{
    Word.Document JoinedDoc = new Word.Document();
    foreach (Word.Document doc in DocstoJoin)
    {
        foreach (Word.Section sec in doc.Sections)
        {
            **????**
        }
    }

    return JoinedDoc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Selection class provides the following methods that can be used to get the job done:

- [Copy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196538(v=office.15).aspx) - copies the specified selection to the Clipboard.
- [Paste](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840284(v=office.15).aspx) - inserts the contents of the Clipboard at the specified selection.

Also you may consider using the [Open XML SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx) if you deal with open XML documents only.